# Should all output be purified in PHP?

Tags: php, security, input, htmlpurifier

I am creating a rather small web application in PHP, where a (trusted) administrator can, amongst other things, store hundreds of objects in a database. The user can enter a number of details about these objects in the form of text fields (an input element with the type attribute set to "text").

The objects with their details are echoed in the form of a table, escaped by the [`htmlspecialchars`](http://php.net/htmlspecialchars) function. This function, however, does not prevent against the malicious use of html tags, for example, the `<script>` tag.

The question is whether all user entered data (every cell in the table) should be purified by something like HTMLPurifier, which is already used elsewhere in the application. And if so, what would be the best way to do it as using HTMLPurifier thousands of times, as there are many details, may cause some serious performance issues.

Comment: It is probably easier to simply use the "Content security police" these days to prevent inline script execution in general. That should be done anyway.

Comment: Why wouldn't `htmlspecialchars` be sufficient to output the text content fields in that table? Or is this about adminstrator-added content being treated differently from the mentioned user-supplied text fields?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> The objects with their details are echoed in the form of a table, escaped by the htmlspecialchars function. This function, however, does not prevent against the malicious use of html tags, for example, the `<script>` tag.

Yes it does. They get harmlessly and correctly output as `&lt;script&gt;`.

> The question is whether all user entered data (every cell in the table) should be purified by something like HTMLPurifier

Nope. You should only use HTMLPurifier on fields where you are deliberately intending to allow the user to enter markup for direct rendering to the page, for example a comment system where the user can type `<i>` for italics.

For other input that you are treating as plain text, `htmlspecialchars` remains the right thing to do when outputting to HTML.

Comment: I checked my code again, and I am ashamed to say that in one scenario an `htmlspecialchars` was missing, which caused the bug. Thanks a lot for the input about HTMLPurifier, I wasn't sure if I used it correctly but now I do!

Comment: Yeah, it's really easy to miss one. It's a shame PHP still has no option to escape-by-default.

Answer (score 1):

Everything should be checked and cleaned before you save it into database. Principle is that you DO NOT TRUST anything which is coming from user.

ALWAYS escape everything.

Or just use tools which will do that for you - like frameworks.

Comment: This is a little bland advise. The question also wasn't about database escaping (which pretty much is a non-issue nowadays unless you've been living under a rock).

Comment: I assumed that if you escape data properly before putting into database, there is just no need to escape them afterwards...

Comment: Occassionally it makes sense to pre-escape stuff. If your legacy-ish application doesn't take care enough, then the better-safe-than-sorry approach (HTML escaping before DB storage) might do. Generally you don't want to obfuscate data just for one output context however.